# While loop error: "Uninitialized local variable used"

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I'm doing an assignment where I modify a program that calculates the factorial of numbers so that the program terminates when the user enters the number '0'. Here is the code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int numb;
    unsigned long fact = 1;

    while (numb > 0)
    {


        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> numb;

        for (int j = numb; j > 0; j--)
        {
            fact *= j;
            cout << "Factorial is " << fact << endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I keep getting getting this error message:

error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'numb' used

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not initializing `numb`. That error is pretty clear.

Comment: This is not even a real error.  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int numb;
unsigned long fact = 1;

while (numb > 0)
```

When you first hit this expression, what is the value of `numb`? The compiler doesn't know either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a

> cout << "Enter a number: ";
>
> cin >> numb;

before the while loop to initialize numb before entering. Then move the existing cout, cin statements to the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make factorial so must make like this (in your variables):
1. Give number
2. Loop with reduced counter( --j)
3. Multiply by counter in loop.
4. After loop, display result (fact).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int numb;
    unsigned long fact = 1;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> numb;
    for (int j = numb; j > 0; --j)
    {
        fact *= j;
    }
    cout << "Factorial is " << fact << endl;
    return 0;
}
```